# With Microsoft Unity, how can I reference a ParameterOverride when using InjectionFactory

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a core library that has a bunch of services accessible through a factory.  It looks something like this:

```
MyServiceFactory.Create<T>(serviceKey);
```

In other libraries I'm trying to reference this factory, and pass in the ServiceKey.  I'm struggling with how to set ServiceKey as a ParameterOverride AND have it be recognized in the InjectionFactory.  When doing a standard RegisterType() the ParameterOverride magically gets injected into every class in the graph that has that parameter.

**Unity Setup**

```
        container.RegisterType<IOrderService>(new InjectionFactory(f=>{

return MyServiceFactory.Create<IOrderService>(REFERENCE_TO_PARAMETEROVERRIDE_FOR_SERVICEKEY);
                    }));
```

**Unity Resolve**

```
public static T Resolve<T>()
        {

            var parameterOverride = new ParameterOverride("serviceKey", new TestingServiceKey());

            return Resolve<T>(parameterOverride);
        }
```